# Reduction in matrix rows using atomic lock and array of mutexes hangs forever on CUDA sm_20

Tags: cuda, atomic

I'm trying to port sm30->sm20 my kernel for min/max reduction on rows of a matrix that also returns index of min/max elements:

```
__global__ void experimental_reduction2D(int *mutexes, float * mat, float * out, int * out_idx, int col_str, int row_seq){
    // thread and block coordinates ...
    int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
    int bDx = blockDim.x; int bDy = blockDim.y;
    int gDx = gridDim.x;
    //
    int Idx = bDx * bx + tx;
    int Idy = bDy * by + ty;
    int gridSize = gDx * bDx;
    //
    float2 vec2_load;
    float  vec1_load;
    float pre_accum = FLT_MAX;
    float pre_accum_tmp;
    int min_index=0;
    int min_index_tmp;
    // massive coalsced loading ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (Idy < row_seq) {
            if (2*Idx+1 < col_str) {
                vec2_load = reinterpret_cast<float2*>(mat)[Idy*(col_str>>1) + Idx];
                if (pre_accum > vec2_load.x){pre_accum = vec2_load.x; min_index = 2*Idx+0;};
                if (pre_accum > vec2_load.y){pre_accum = vec2_load.y; min_index = 2*Idx+1;};
            } else if (2*Idx < col_str) {
                vec1_load = mat[Idy*col_str + 2*Idx];
                if (pre_accum > vec1_load){pre_accum = vec1_load; min_index = 2*Idx;};
            }
        }
        Idx += gridSize;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    // using register shuffling within the warp - blazing fast!
    pre_accum_tmp=__shfl_down(pre_accum,8,16);
    min_index_tmp=__shfl_down(min_index,8,16);
    if (pre_accum > pre_accum_tmp){ pre_accum=pre_accum_tmp; min_index=min_index_tmp;};
    pre_accum_tmp=__shfl_down(pre_accum,4,16);
    min_index_tmp=__shfl_down(min_index,4,16);
    if (pre_accum > pre_accum_tmp){ pre_accum=pre_accum_tmp; min_index=min_index_tmp;};
    pre_accum_tmp=__shfl_down(pre_accum,2,16);
    min_index_tmp=__shfl_down(min_index,2,16);
    if (pre_accum > pre_accum_tmp){ pre_accum=pre_accum_tmp; min_index=min_index_tmp;};
    pre_accum_tmp=__shfl_down(pre_accum,1,16);
    min_index_tmp=__shfl_down(min_index,1,16);
    if (pre_accum > pre_accum_tmp){ pre_accum=pre_accum_tmp; min_index=min_index_tmp;};
    //
    // global storing to be done atomically ...
    if ((tx == 0) && (Idy < row_seq)) {
        lock(&mutexes[Idy]);
        float old_val = out[Idy];
        if (pre_accum < old_val) {
            out[Idy] = pre_accum;
            out_idx[Idy] = min_index;
        }
        unlock(&mutexes[Idy]);
    }
}
```

Which I was launching in a configuration:

```
dim3 block(16,16);
dim3 grid((COLUMNS-1)/(2*BLOCK.X*32)+1 , (ROWS-1)/BLOCK.Y+1);
```

where lock functions are:

```
__device__ void lock(int *pmutex) {
    while(atomicCAS(pmutex, 0, 1) != 0);
}

__device__ void unlock(int *pmutex) {
    atomicExch(pmutex, 0);
}
```

and I initialize `int *mutexes` right before kernel launch, like so:

```
int *mutex_array;
Safe_CUDA_Call(cudaMalloc((void**)&mutex_array, NUM_OF_MUTEXES*sizeof(int)));
Safe_CUDA_Call(cudaMemset(mutex_array, 0, NUM_OF_MUTEXES*sizeof(int)));
```

where `NUM_OF_MUTEXES==ROWS`.

For sm_20 I replaced kepler shuffles back to shared memory reduction of last16 elements, and it works slower but correctly on sm_30 and sm_35. However on an actual sm_20 device it hangs forever!

Removing `lock, unlock` from kernels revives it! I checked with sm_20 specs it sounds like atomicCAS and atomicExch should work the same way as on >=sm30. I'm aware of the issue, when several threads within a warp are trying to access the same mutex, but it doesn't seem to be the case here, because I have 2 threads in a warp that access two different mutexes `mutexes[Idy]` and `mutexes[Idy-next]`. Am I missing something here?

sm_20 kernel just in case:

```
__global__ void experimental_reduction2D(int *mutexes, float * mat, float * out, int * out_idx, int col_str, int row_seq){
    //
    // thread and block coordinates ...
    int tx = threadIdx.x; int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int bx = blockIdx.x; int by = blockIdx.y;
    int bDx = blockDim.x; int bDy = blockDim.y;
    int gDx = gridDim.x; //int gDy = gridDim.y;
    //
    int Idx = bDx * bx + tx;
    int Idy = bDy * by + ty;
    int gridSize = gDx * bDx;
    // int index_to_load;
    //
    float2 vec2_load;
    float  vec1_load;
    // classic ...
    __shared__ float scratch[2*16*16];
    // initialize pre_result ...
    //
    float *pre_result = &scratch[0];
    int *min_result = (int *)&scratch[16*16];
    // init shared mem arrays ...
    pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = FLT_MAX;
    min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    //
    // massive coalsced loading ...
    for (int i = 0; i < WORK_str; i++) {
     //
     if (Idy < row_seq) {
         if (2*Idx+1 < col_str) {
             // index_to_load = Idy*(col_str>>1) + Idx;
             vec2_load = reinterpret_cast<float2*>(mat)[Idy*(col_str>>1) + Idx];
             if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > vec2_load.x){pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = vec2_load.x; min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = 2*Idx+0;};
             if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > vec2_load.y){pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = vec2_load.y; min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = 2*Idx+1;};
             // pre_accum = min(pre_accum, vec2_load.y);
         } else if (2*Idx < col_str) {
             vec1_load = mat[Idy*col_str + 2*Idx];
             if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > vec1_load){pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = vec1_load; min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = 2*Idx;};
             // pre_accum = min(pre_accum, vec1_load);
         }
     }
     Idx += gridSize;
    }
    //
    __syncthreads();
    //
    //
    if (tx<8) {
        if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+8]){
            pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+8];
            min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx+8];
        }
    }; __syncthreads();
    if (tx<4) {
        if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+4]){
            pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+4];
            min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx+4];
        }
    }; __syncthreads();
    if (tx<2) {
        if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+2]){
            pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+2];
            min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx+2];
        }
    }; __syncthreads();
    if (tx<1) {
        if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] > pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+1]){
            pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx+1];
            min_result[bDx*ty+tx] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx+1];
        }
    }; __syncthreads();
    //
    // this isn't working ...
    if ((tx == 0) && (Idy < row_seq)) {
        lock(&mutexes[Idy]);
        float old_val = out[Idy];
        if (pre_result[bDx*ty+tx] < old_val) {
            out[Idy] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx];
            out_idx[Idy] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx];
        }
        unlock(&mutexes[Idy]);
    }
    //
    // // this is wrong (doesn;t do what i want), but it works ...
    // if ((tx == 0) && (Idy < row_seq)) {
    //     // printf("%d",mutexes[Idy]);
    //     out[Idy] = pre_result[bDx*ty+tx];
    //     out_idx[Idy] = min_result[bDx*ty+tx];
    // }
    //
    //
}
```

Comment: Voting to close.  Provide a simple, complete, compilable code (not a bunch of snippets), that demonstrates the hang.  It seems like you should be able to do this in about 30 lines of code, or so.  And your expectation about multiple threads in a warp acquiring locks is not correct.  It can easily lead to a hang condition for the lock mechanism you have provided, even when there are separate locks. You might want to study [this question](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/762279/cuda-programming-and-performance/problem-with-lock-using-atomiccas/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock mechanism is broken, when there are multiple threads in a warp competing for locks, whether the same or different locks.

Due to your 16x16 threadblock, you will have 2 threads in each warp, for which `threadIdx.x` is zero:

```
if ((tx == 0) && (Idy < row_seq)) {
```

These two threads will have different `Idy` values.  You will also have another block in your 2D grid, for which the same `Idy` values will be used by the corresponding threads to select locks:

```
    lock(&mutexes[Idy]);
```

To make this crystal clear, let's consider warp 0 in `blockIdx.x` = 0 and `blockIdx.y` = 0:

```
warp lane:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ... 31
threadIdx.x  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  0  1  2  3  4 ... 15
Idy:         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1      1
```

If you now change `blockIdx.x` from 0 to 1, there is *no change* in the above diagram for warp 0.

That means blocks (0,0) and (1,0) will have warps that are *competing for the same locks*.

Now, suppose we have warp 0 from block (0,0) that happens to hit this line of code:

```
    lock(&mutexes[Idy]);
```

And let's suppose warp 0 from block (1,0) hits the same line of code.

This means thread 0 in each warp 0 (from the 2 blocks) will be competing for lock 0 (`Idy` = 0), and thread 16 in each warp 0 will be competing for lock 1.

What happens if block 0 thread 0 wins lock 0, but block 1 thread 16 wins lock 1?

You have deadlock.  Niether warp can proceed past the while loop in the lock function, until *all threads in that warp that are competing for locks* have successfully acquired their lock.  But this can't happen until the corresponding warp in the other block releases a lock, which also can't happen.

The lock mechanism is broken, when multiple warps have threads competing for the same lock(s).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is crystal clear now indeed! But what is striking about this, is that this broken code worked just fine (giving correct results) for sm>=30 (K20 and GeForce gtx660), while [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/762279/cuda-programming-and-performance/problem-with-lock-using-atomiccas/) someone broke sm_35 machine by doing same exercise with 32 threads/warp against 32 mutexes. I'm guessing sm30+ instruction per lockstep was saving me from deadlock in my case of 2 conflicting threads/warp (my typical gridDim.x was about 10).

Comment: The details of grid size and warp execution order will impact the ability to repro the result.  Warp execution order may vary from GPU to GPU, as it is an unspecified aspect of scheduling.  But the code is fundamentally broken.  The fact that you can find a situation where it does not hang doesn't mean there is no defect.

Comment: Absolutely, and I'm glad that I realized it with your help and an actual sm_20 device! I'm done with atomics now, instead I'll implement iterative reduction with intermediate/scratch array now. If by any chance you happen to know any good links for tutorials/examples of a general case reduction (reduction in more than one block), please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: The starting point for understanding general parallel reduction would be the [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and the associated PDF document.  You may also want to investigate [cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html).